# How to select multiple like and other condition mysql

Tags: mysql

Good day, I am a newbie programmer. I would like to ask what is the problem with my code? All I want sir/ma'am to view the user with letter "a" in firstname,middlename and lastname and status is equal to 1 and usertype is not equal to the word "Admin".

The code below showing other user record, even the usertype is Admin. Please help me sir.

This is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE usertype != 'Admin' AND firstname LIKE '%a%' OR middlename LIKE '%a%' OR lastname LIKE '%a%' AND userstatus = '1'
```

Please help me. I see some post here that using multiple like, Sorry if my english is too bad. Thanks in adavance

Comment: You say 'and and and' in your question and write 'and or or and' in your SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to group your `LIKE` statements. You can use brackets for that, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE usertype != 'Admin' 
AND (
    firstname LIKE '%a%' 
    OR middlename LIKE '%a%' 
    OR lastname LIKE '%a%'
)
AND userstatus = '1'
```

Or put them the way you want. However I would recommend you to prevent statements like this, because the can become very ill performing, especially when the wildcharacters are on both sides. But I assume that is just as an example here.

*EDIT*: See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2740bb/1) for fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE usertype != 'Admin' AND (firstname LIKE '%a%' OR middlename LIKE '%a%' OR lastname LIKE '%a%') AND userstatus = '1'
```

Comment: Can you like elaborate a little? Somethin' about operator precedence?Anything?)